# Number of integers in relation to Pythagorean triples with some quadratic relations

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, pythagorean-triples

Given an integer $m>0$ possibly composite we can find non-negative integers which are not equivalent to $0\bmod m$ with
$$ab+cd\equiv0\bmod m$$.

Is there any integer quadruples bounded in $[0,m-1]^4$ are there that also satisfy
$$bd-ac\equiv0\bmod m$$
$$a^2+d^2=e^2$$
$$b^2+c^2=f^2$$
for some integers $0<e,f\leq\sqrt m$?

If $(a,d,e)$ and $(b,c,f)$ are primitive Pythagorean triples then $a,b$ are of form $2m'$ are $d,c$ are of form $m'^2-1$ and $e,f$ are of form $m
^2+1$.

So there are only two integers $m_1$ and $m_2$ that parameterize $a,d$ and $b,c$ respectively with
$$bd=2m_1(m_2^2-1)$$
$$ac=2m_2(m_1^2-1)$$
$$ab=4m_1m_2$$
$$cd=(m_1^2-1)(m_2^2-1)$$

and we seek

$$4m_1m_2+(m_1^2-1)(m_2^2-1)\equiv0\bmod m$$
$$2m_1(m_2^2-1)-2m_2(m_1^2-1)\equiv0\bmod m.$$

---

We also have $$\begin{bmatrix}a&d\\d&-a\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}b\\c\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}b&c\\-c&b\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\d\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\ell m\\\ell'm\end{bmatrix}$$ at some integers with $\ell\ell'\neq0$.